# Why is this code is not implementing Markov Chain

Tags: markov-process

My MOOC course says that this code is not implementing Markov Chain

```py
import random
N = 20; position = 0
for iter in range(1000000):
    if random.uniform(0.0, 1.0) > 0.2: 
        if random.uniform(0.0, 1.0) < 0.5:
            position = (position + 1) % N
        if random.uniform(0.0, 1.0) > 0.5:
            position = (position - 1) % N
```

The goal is to implement a Monte Carlo algorithm such that it remains with probability 0.2 on the present site, and moves with probability 0.4 to the left and with probability 0.4 to the right.
[image]

I added the log function and sees that the probability is correct. My hunch is that Markov Chain must follow a tabular-rasa fashion, and the code above does not. Tabular-rasa assures equiprobability, but I could not link that to the reason the code is not a Monte Carlo chain implementation.

The code for logging:

```py
import random
N = 20; position = 0
RUN = 1000000
log = {'stay': 0., 'inc': 0., 'dec': 0.}
for iter in range(RUN):
    if random.uniform(0.0, 1.0) > 0.2:
        if random.uniform(0.0, 1.0) < 0.5:
            log['inc'] += 1
        if random.uniform(0.0, 1.0) > 0.5:
            log['dec'] += 1
    else:
        log['stay'] += 1

print(log)
print(log['inc'] / RUN,  log['dec'] / RUN, log['stay'] / RUN)
```

Comment: The code does not agree with the probabilities you quote.  Your code increments the position with probability $(1-0.2)\times 0.5=0.4$ and then can decrement the position only with probability $(1-0.2)\times(1-0.5)*0.5 = 0.2,$ thereby staying put with a chance of $1-0.4-0.2=0.4.$ Perhaps the claim is that the code is not implementing the *intended* Markov chain?

Comment: Do you have a direct quote from the course? The definition for a Markov chain isn't complicated and I don't see how your process would fail to qualify.

Comment: @whuber Yes, it is a false example. I would edit the post to make it clearer. Thank you. @ Ryan It is indeed false, as said in the answer of @ Xi'an below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code

```
    if random.uniform(0.0, 1.0) > 0.2: 
      if random.uniform(0.0, 1.0) < 0.5:
        position = (position + 1) % N
      if random.uniform(0.0, 1.0) > 0.5:
        position = (position - 1) % N
```

relies on *three independent Uniform draws* and generates a Markov chain that remains at the same position with probability
$$0.2+0.8\times(0.5^2+0.5^2)=0.6$$
that moves by one (right) with probability
$$0.8\times 0.5^2=0.2$$
and moves by minus one (left) with probability
$$0.8\times 0.5^2=0.2$$
Note also that the `log` counter does not follow the chain moves properly.

The alternate code

```
    if random.uniform(0.0, 1.0) > 0.2: 
      if random.uniform(0.0, 1.0) < 0.5:
        position = (position + 1) % N
      else:
        position = (position - 1) % N
```

uses *only two independent Uniform variates* generates a Markov chain that stays static with probability 0.2, moves left or right with identical probability 0.4.

Comment: Why don't you use only one uniform draw between 0 and 1 ? With event "stay at same position" if <0.2, elif <0.6 "go right" else go left.

Comment: @Rodolphe: my point was to signal the mistake in the original code, which was due to the use of a third loop. Simulating directly one of the three events is obviously feasible with a single uniform.